# Resizing whole text containing different fonts in TextEdit

Tags: macos, keyboard, font, textedit, internationalization

My text file uses two fonts, Helvetica for usual text and the ALPHABETUM-Unicode 
specialized font for rare ancient characters.
  The system handles it nicely, as the sizes of the ALPHABETUM characters
are harmonious with those of the Helvetica characters, even though they’re 
not of the same font.

After writing dozens of pages, I belatedly realized that the presentation would
be much better if I downsized all the characters.

So I tried « Select All (Command A)» and « Smaller (Command -) », but the result
was predictably ugly, as the system failed to handle both fonts at the same time.

In the resulting text, while the Helvetica characters are downsized correctly, the 
ALPHABETUM characters have kept their initial size (20), and TextEdit mistakenly
sees them as « Helvetica characters with size 1 », so I cannot even resize them manually.

Is there a clean solution to my problem ? (I am open to solutions using other tools
than TextEdit).

Comment: When you select text in Alphabetum, do you not see that font name selected in Format > Font > Show Fonts?

Comment: @TomGewecke Both in Format > Font > Show Fonts, and in the ruler on top of the TextEdit window, I see "Helvetica". It seems that the "downsize all" operation somewhat merged the two fonts into one.

Comment: I would try copy/pasting the text to Pages or LibreOffice or Word and see if that helps.